# How can i find an error using databinding and dagger 2?

Tags: android, data-binding, dagger-2

I updated Android Studio a few days ago. And update sdk, build tools and architect components

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 27

arch_core_version = "1.1.0"
arch_room_version = "1.1.0-alpha1"
arch_lifecycle = "1.1.0"
//tool_version = "26.0.2"
tool_version = "27.0.3"
//support_version = "26.1.0"
support_version = "27.0.2"
dagger_version = "2.14.1"
retrofit_version = "2.3.0"
stetho = "1.5.0"
okhttp = "3.9.0"
constraint_layout_version = "1.1.0-beta1"
glide_version = "4.2.0"
timber_version = "4.5.1"
androidasync = "2.+"
cookie = "v1.0.1"
firebase = "11.8.0"
```

Since my application is not compiled.
I get errors like

```
app/src/main/java/com.example/ui/home/HomeFragment.java
Error:(20, 45) error: package com.example.databinding does not exist
Error:(33, 48) error: cannot find symbol class FragmentHomeBinding
```

and similar for the another fragments and activities.

Last time i compiled my application half a year ago. There were no errors.

I found i need compile with --stacktrace and --debug

i get errors

```
app/src/main/java/com/example/app/ui/home/HomeFragment.java:20: error: package com.example.app.databinding does not exist
import com.example.app.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;
                                  ^
symbol: class FragmentHomeBinding

app/src/main/java/com/example/app/ui/common/BaseFragment.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
private android.databinding.DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent = new BaseDataBindingComponent(this);
                           ^
symbol:   class DataBindingComponent
location: package android.databinding

...

[ERROR] [system.err] 100 errors
...
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
...
[org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

And similar for the another fragments and activities.
Full log over 14 000 lines

I tried to change gradle to 3.1.0-alpha06 and add android.databinding.enableV2=true.
But i have the same errors.

Google says it's error in my xml. I'm not sure I made changes in the last half year or no.

I tried add some error in my other application who compile success after update, but i have the error in console log. I can't get the same errors like in my first application so I have no idea where to look for an error.

Comment: Have you seen the Dagger + Databinding note in [Dagger's doc](https://github.com/google/dagger#android-gradle), and also [this Github issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/306) which is very similar to yours

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not see this :) It helped me find and fix the error!

Comment: No problem! Maybe you can answer this question (and mark as solution) so that others can benefit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mustafa Berkay Mutlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2708768/mustafa-berkay-mutlu) 's comment to help me solve the problem.

[Note in Dagger's doc](https://github.com/google/dagger#android-gradle)

[Github issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/306)

Android studio show only 100 errors by default.

I added

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500" // or whatever number you want
  }
}
```

to my build.gradle (Project) and in 246 line I saw the error that broke my application.

I had this code

```
@Query("select id from Message where dialogId = :dialogId order by id limit 1")
List<Message> lastId(long dialogId);
```

The code was working before last update but now i get error that Message class have more fields than the query returns.

I added new class

```
public class OnlyId {
    private final int id;

    public OnlyId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Commenting  #android.databinding.enableV2=true in gradle.properties is also helpful on Android Studio 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Add into gradle(top level gradle)

```
allprojects {
     gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "500"
        }
    }
}
```